# Data Extraction & Pattern Matching

Tags: regex, perl, bash, awk

I am trying to write a script that can extract data and put it in a definite format. I have data like this.

```
Person#1: 
Name: 
Age: 
House.No: 
Streetname: 

Person#2: 
Weight: 
Age: 
Name: 
Date of Birth: 

Person#3: 
Name: 
Age: 
Height:
```

The number of attributes for a given person are not the same in all cases but have a common attribute Age. I want a script to extract the Person# and Age and put in a format like

```
 Person#1/Age

 Person#2/Age 

 Person#3/Age etc.
```

Can anybody help me out either with a scripting language like Perl,Awk.Any useful suggestions on grep and shell script are appreciated.

Comment: Please add example data, desired output and your efforts so far.

Comment: Looks like either a multi-line regex or a state machine problem...

Comment: awk '{if ($1 ~ /Person/ && /$2 ~ /Age//) print $0}';

Comment: grep -w "Age" <file_name>

Answer (score 0):

If you have data like this:

```
Person#1:
Name: Frank
Age: 17
House.No:
Streetname:

Person#2:
Weight:
Name: Peter
Age: 15
Date of Birth:

Person#3:
Name: Mara
Age: 22
Height:
```

Then you can use this `awk`

```
awk '/Person/ {p=$1} /Name/ {n=$2} /Age/ {print p,n,$2}'
Person#1: Frank 17
Person#2: Peter 15
Person#3: Mara 22
```